# Downloaded JPEG file not recognised on iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, jpeg

When I download a JPEG file from and ASP Web Forms application using the following code, the image is not shown when the application runs from a browser (Safari)  on an iPhone 5 - only a screen offering to open the file in Dropbox. Using Opera the download does not appear at all. It appears that IOS does not recognize the downloaded file as a displayable image. The download occurs as expected from a Windows desktop.

```
string sDownloadFile = Session["strImagePath"].ToString();
string sFileName = Session["sFileName"].ToString();
Response.ContentType = "application/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + sFileName + "'");
Response.TransmitFile(sDownloadFile);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Possibly try ensuring that `filename` is wrapped int `"` instead of single quotes like `filename=\"" + sFileName + "\""` or try calling `Response.Clear()` before you begin building your response to make sure it is empty

Comment: Tried these - no help. Showing image context menu (Open or Save) by tapping image  and selecting Save works OK with Safari and Opera on iPhone 5, so problem is with my code rather than iPhone settings.

Comment: You could try using [.BinaryWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite?view=netframework-4.8) instead potentially? Not sure why `TransmitFile` wouldn't work but it's worth a shot. I'm not seeing a reason why the iPhone wouldn't be able to download otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below (BinaryWrite rather than TransmitFile) I found that the iPhone would recognize downloaded file as a JPEG.

```
           string sFileName = Session["sFileName"].ToString();// Original file name// System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sDownloadFile);
           byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sDownloadFile);
           SendFileBytesToResponse(fileBytes, sFileName);

private static void SendFileBytesToResponse(byte[] bytes, string sFileName)
       {
           if (bytes != null)
           {
               string downloadName = sFileName;
               System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
               response.Clear();
               response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/jpeg");
               response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                  "attachment; filename=" + downloadName + "; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());
               response.Flush();
               response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
               response.Flush();
               response.End();
           }           
       }
```